# Do you use express.static(‘public’) OR (path.join(__dirname, ‘public’))?

Tags: express

My tree:

```
├── app.js
├── data
 │   └── stuff.json
├── package.json
├── public
 │   ├── index.html
 │   ├── main.js
├── routes
    └── api.js
```

Below are two lines I’ve used in my app.js file in order to serve the static file public/index.html

This first option works fine.  As I understand it, it directs the user to the public directory relative to app.js:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

The following second line doesn’t work.  As I understand it, this is the absolute path to the public directory.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

The https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html seems to suggest the first option, yet most web sites and books encourage the second.  Why/When is the second encouraged? And why doesn’t it work for me in this case?

Comment: `express.static` just delegates to `path.resolve()`. So I would `console.log` the path you get for both cases.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  (path.join(_dirname+'/public')) logs out the absolute path whereas the other case yields a relative path.  The absolute path doesn't seem of any use to me here, yet it's often used - I wonder in what scenario might it prove useful?